# Datetable doesn't work at all if I put the datepicker function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

So I have 2 plugins they are datatable and datepicker, If i put the javascript the datepicker the datatables no longer work, and if I remove it the datepicker doesn't work.

Here's the code for date picker

```
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1  w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });

  </script>
```

Here's the code for datatables

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#listTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
```

Well here my whole code for index where I put all the javascript functions and link

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>
        <?php include ('title.php');?>
    </title>

    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/LOGO.png">    

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/gen_validatorv31.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


    <?php
        session_start();    
        include ("checkSession.php");
        include ("nav.php");
        include ("pagecontent.php");
    ?>





    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#listTable').DataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": 50
  } );
        });

    </script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1  w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });

  </script>
   <script>
   $(function() {
      var startDate = "1935";
      var endDate = new Date().getFullYear() - 18;    
      var interval = startDate + ":" + endDate;
    $( "#from2" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: interval,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });



    $( "#to2" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from2" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for the long post, I don't know what to do and what is the error :(

Comment: You are loading jquery twice,  you have 3 `<script></script>` in row for no reasonlock you can combine them into one `<script>` b, you have `include ("pagecontent.php");`, that doesn't let us know what your table and page content is, instead provide static contnet on here so that we can reproduce and track it down instead of figuring out what your page content is.. thank you

Comment: Also in `$( "#from2" ).datepicker({onClose:})` you have `$( "#to" ).datepicker();`, do you mean `('#to')` or `$('#to2')` on this line?

Answer (score 1):

If you check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/67uk2e20/2/), I didn't do anything to your code except cleaning it, combining the 3 `script` tags into one, wrapped the `$(document).ready()` function all around your js code and that's it - *well beside creating the html static content* - and you see that everything is working like it should, all datepickers, setting 1935 to the second `from` and full control of Datatable over `#listTable`.. everything working and this is the clean version of your JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //============================= DataTable
    $('#listTable').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 50
    });


    //============================= DatePicker 1
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: "+1  w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        yearRange: '1935:' + (new Date).getFullYear(),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        yearRange: '1935:' + (new Date).getFullYear(),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });


    //============================= DatePicker2
    var startDate = "1935";
    var endDate = new Date().getFullYear() - 18;
    var interval = startDate + ":" + endDate;
    $("#from2").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        yearRange: interval,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $("#to2").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        yearRange: '1935:' + (new Date).getFullYear(),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

});
```